# Exclude specific characters from matching in a python regex exercise

Tags: python, regex

I have the following exercise. I need to fill in the list of regular expressions only. I don't touch any other part of the code. I am stuck on number 5 (Neither a's nor b's, but "" allowed) and 7 (Exactly two words, regardless of white spaces).

```
import re

# List of strings used for testing.
slist = [ "aaabbb", "aaaaaa", "abbaba", "aaa", "gErbil ottEr",
    "tango samba rumba", " hello world ", " Hello World " ]

# List of regular expressions to be completed by the student.
relist = [
    r"",  # 1. Only a's followed by only b's, including ""
    r"",  # 2. Only a's, including ""
    r"",  # 3. Only a's and b's, in any order, including "" 
    r"",  # 4. Exactly three a's
    r"",  # 5. Neither a's nor b's, but "" allowed
    r"",  # 6. An even number of a's (and nothing else)
    r"",  # 7. Exactly two words, regardless of white spaces
    r"",  # 8. Contains a word that ends in "ba"
    r""   # 9. Contains a word that starts with a capital
]

for s in slist:
    print( s, ':', sep='', end=' ' )
    for i in range( len( relist ) ):
        m = re.search( relist[i], s )
        if m:
            print( i+1, end=' ' )
    print()
```

I have come up with the following:

```
import re

# List of strings used for testing.
slist = [ "aaabbb", "aaaaaa", "abbaba", "aaa", "gErbil ottEr",
    "tango samba rumba", " hello world ", " Hello World " ]

# List of regular expressions to be completed by the student.
relist = [
    r"(^a+)(b*$)"           ,  # 1. Only a's followed by only b's, including ""
    r"(^a)(a+$)"            ,  # 2. Only a's, including ""
    r"^[a|b]+[a|b]$"        ,  # 3. Only a's and b's, in any order, including "" 
    r"^a{3}$"               ,  # 4. Exactly three a's
    r"[^a|^b]"              ,  # 5. Neither a's nor b's, but "" allowed
    r"^(a{2})+$"            ,  # 6. An even number of a's (and nothing else)
    r"^\s*\w+\s+\w+$"       ,  # 7. Exactly two words, regardless of white spaces
    r".*ba\b"               ,  # 8. Contains a word that ends in "ba"
    r".*\b\s+[A-Z]"            # 9. Contains a word that starts with a capital
]

for s in slist:
    print( s, ':', sep='', end=' ' )
    for i in range( len( relist ) ):
        m = re.search( relist[i], s )
        if m:
            print( i+1, end=' ' )
    print()
```

This does not give the expected outcome which is:

```
aaabbb: 1 3   
aaaaaa: 1 2 3 6    
abbaba: 3 8    
aaa: 1 2 3 4     
bEver ottEr: 7    
tango samba rumba: 8     
 hello world : 5 7     
 Hello World : 5 7 9
```

I have looked for hours and while there are many regex queries, from them, I can not get the solution to my problem. The problems are

```
    r"[^a|^b]"              ,  # 5. Neither a's nor b's, but "" allowed
```

where I just don't know how to exclude a character. If I compare with abc, the programme will happily match the c and allow abc. Is there a way to say that, if there is a specific letter present, than it is no match, end of story?

```
    r"^\s*\w+\s+\w+$"       ,  # 7. Exactly two words, regardless of white spaces
```

I'm not even sure what I'm looking for here. This code recognises gErbil ottEr as two words, but despite the \s*, it fails to spot Hello World which starts with a whitespace. I just don't understand what the problem is.

Please note I can't change the code other than those bits. So any other re.modules are no solution. I have also come across negative lookahead, but my course has not (yet?) touched upon those. I've reread the chapter multiple times. As such, I don't think I'm supposed to be using that either. I am to use:

- special sequences ( \b \B \d \D \n \r \s \S \t \w \W / \ " ' ^ $ . )
- repetition ( * + ? {p,q} {p,} {p} )
- also explained: ( b[aio]ll (ab)+ (a|b) (a-dghy-z) )

I know there may be easier or different methods for solving this, but the exercise is about learning the above methods before moving on to the next part of the chapter. With only the expressions mentioned above, how can I solve point 5 and point 7?

Comment: `" hello world "` has a trailing whitespace as well as a leading whitespace. So your `\s*` at the start of the regex gets you halfway there...

Comment: Whoever gave you this exercise doesn't seem to be a Pythonista; in Python we prefer PEP8 and `enumerate()` to `( ` and `for _ in range(len(...))`.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments! I can move on in the chapter now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#7 is the only trick question since it throws in the whitespace is irrelavent. In reality it has nothing to do with whitespace.

The questions with `including ""` denote the empty string which has to be accounted for I guess.

```
import re

# List of strings used for testing.
slist = [ "aaabbb", "aaaaaa", "abbaba", "aaa", "gErbil ottEr",
    "tango samba rumba", " hello world ", " Hello World " ]

# List of regular expressions to be completed by the student.
relist = [
    r"^(a+b*)?$"              ,  # 1. Only a's followed by only b's, including ""
    r"^(a+)?$"                ,  # 2. Only a's, including ""
    r"^([ab]+)?$"             ,  # 3. Only a's and b's, in any order, including "" 
    r"^a{3}$"                 ,  # 4. Exactly three a's
    r"^([^ab]+)?$"            ,  # 5. Neither a's nor b's, but "" allowed
    r"^(aa)+$"                ,  # 6. An even number of a's (and nothing else)
    r"^\W*(\w+\b\W*){2}$"     ,  # 7. Exactly two words, regardless of white spaces
    r"ba\b"                   ,  # 8. Contains a word that ends in "ba"
    r"\b[A-Z]"                   # 9. Contains a word that starts with a capital
]

for s in slist:
    print( s, ':', sep='', end=' ' )
    for i in range( len( relist ) ):
        m = re.search( relist[i], s )
        if m:
            print( i+1, end=' ' )
    print()
```

Output

```
aaabbb: 1 3   
aaaaaa: 1 2 3 6    
abbaba: 3 8    
aaa: 1 2 3 4     
bEver ottEr: 7    
tango samba rumba: 8     
 hello world : 5 7     
 Hello World : 5 7 9
```

Comment: Could you explain,  why are you using `(a+)?` and not simple `a*`, and so on?

Comment: Thank you for organising it for me like that. That was very helpful as I could check how to write it.

Comment: @markalex - In the spirit of the exercise all _`including ""`_ items were handled as an afterthought and done en-masse after the main conditions were satisfied. Because I didn't add one more layer of reduction lets the students have the opportunity to read and correlate the regex parts as stated. I don't want to blow peoples minds and have to ask more questions beyond the provided solutions.